# react-native Keyboard.dismiss() not working after autofill on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard, expo, autofill

I am developing a react-native app using expo.

On my signIn screen I do have two TextInputs (with textContentType username and password).
I do have multiple places where I'm calling `Keyboard.dismiss()` (from a wrapping Touchable, from other Buttons etc.) which works fine for most usecases.

My problem is that after I successfully used password autofill on iOS (via fingerprint) first the keyboard hides and reshows automatically (fireing all the usual keyboard events) which looks strange but is acceptable but afterwards the keyboard is no longer reacting to any  `Keyboard.dismiss()` calls untill I focus another TextInput.

There seems to be a similar issue with the "use strong password" keyboard overlay.

Here my versions:

```
"expo": "^34.0.1",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Running in the Expo client on iOS 13.2.3

Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit:

I stripped down the problem to the most basic version. The dismiss button works fine untill I use the password autofill on the iOS device.

https://github.com/SebastianRoese/tryouts/tree/master/keyboard-dismiss-problem

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Keyboard } from 'react-native'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <TextInput style={styles.textinput} textContentType="username" />
            <TextInput style={styles.textinput} secureTextEntry textContentType="password" />
            <Button title="Dismiss Keyboard" onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        paddingVertical: '15%',
        backgroundColor: '#1e1e1e',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    textinput: {
        marginVertical: 10,
        padding: 10,
        width: '70%',
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: '#ababab',
    },
})

export default App
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code for the entire component where you're having problems?

Comment: Hi @James, i added a stripped down version that allows me to consistently reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading from Expo SDK 34 to Expo SDK 38 the problem is no longer reproducable.

Seems like it was an issue in al least Expo SDK Version 34.